# Let $(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ be an ordered triple of pairwise distinct plane in $K^3$. There is two possibles types of relative arrangement of such triples.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ be an ordered triple of pairwise distinct plane in $K^3$. Prove that there is two possibles types of relative arrangement of such triples characterized by the fact that $\dim L_1\cap L_2\cap L_3 = 0$ or $1$.

In fact I imagine that I have to manipulate certains inequalities, like, taking two of these spaces, $\dim (L_1\cap L_2) + \dim (L_1 + L_2) = 2 + 2.$ But I really don't know to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to consider the normal vector to each plane, say $(V_1,V_2,V_3)$ (you can think on $K^3=\mathbb{R}^3$ with standard inner product. The ideas should be translatable to the general case.)

Now, there are only 'three' possibilities for relative arrangements of the normal vectors: they span either a one dimensional, a two dimensional or a three dimensional vector space.

They can't span a one dimensional vector space, since it would make all three planes the same. On the other hand, if thy span a three dimensional space, then the intersection of the planes is $\{0\}$, therefore, it stands for  $\mathrm{dim}L_1\cap L_2\cap L_3=\{0\}$. When the three vectors span a two-dimensional subspace, the orthogonal complement to the last must be contained on all the three spaces, what settles the question.

Obs.: To be very formal,  one should clarify what the exercise means by 'relative arrangement'. A good option would be to assume two arrangements as relatively the same if and only if there is a linear isomorphism that sends one to the other. However, I am not sure if this assumption would keep the exercise true (but let us leave at least this part as an exercise ;) )

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I imagine that by relative arrangement the books means that, what are all possibles positions between these planes? What endorses my idea is that he asks for, what is the position that should be considered as "the general one?". Even more, the book assumes that what defines these arrangement are the invariantes dimension's of intersection and sum of these spaces.